# Entity Groups, JPA and the one write per second limit (app engine)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

I have two entities, `parent` and `child`, that have a `OneToMany relationship`. The parent has an `@Owned` annotation for the child class. There is no relationship back. (from child to parent)

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Owned
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Child> children;

    .........

}


@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;

    public String value;

    .........

    public int hashCode() {
         ... based on this.value ...
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
         ... based on this.value ...
   }

}
```

**Question 1:** Does this setup resemble an entity group where Parent is the ancestor? The following two statements do return an equal Key:

```
- child.getId().qv.getId().getParent()
- KeyFactory.createKey("Parent", parent.getId())
```

---

**Question 2:** Should the following code take about ten seconds to execute? It runs in about 223 milliseconds:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    parent = em.find(Parent.class, parentId);

    child = new Child("value" + i);
    parent.addChild(child)

    em.merge(parent)

    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

The reason why I think it should take 10 seconds is because of this statement in the Google App Engine Documentation:

> "However, the rate at which you can write to the same entity group is limited to 1 write to the entity group per second."

in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are you running on the local development server or production?
The local development server doesn't mimic the performance characteristics of production exactly.

The limit is placed as a guideline.  You may get better performance than that in bursts.  However, if you try a significantly long period of high writes, you will get exceptions.

The performance limit on the datastore writes won't slow down your code execution.  They'll throw exceptions when the transactional writes fail.  Make sure you have some exception handler to check whether this occurs.

Comment: I ran this code locally and on the production server. In the production Server the transaction took about 1 second and 500 milliseconds. 

I think I understand your point. It is just very weird that the documentation specifically says it is limited to one write per second. 

One thing I noticed is that if I run this code in a transaction context it is not significantly slower than without. In fact it is sometimes faster. Is this normal, or is it because it is just a simulation.?

Comment: I suspect if you run the loop 1000 times instead of 10, you will start seeing transaction failure exceptions.  As I mentioned, the transaction context won't affect the performance significantly, but it will throw exceptions if the transaction fails.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Parent indeed looks like the ancestor.

Q2: Why would it take 10 seconds? I see nothing that would imply that this MUST be the case. So my answer to this is no.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.
It should take 10 seconds because of this:
"However, the rate at which you can write to the same entity group is limited to 1 write to the entity group per second."
in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore